# Automation of database creation and command execution in Sybase ASE

Tags: maven, sap-ase

I have been automating the creation of tables in Hana Db using HDBSQL and pyhdb now I want to do the same automation using maven in Sybase ASE, is there any way this can be done?
an alternate way of asking this would be that is there any Sybase equivalent of hdbsql command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command-line utility for ASE is called 'isql'. It is part of every ASE installation and can also be installed separately as part of the client-only install (SDK).

Comment: Rob is this feature available in HCP as well?

Comment: if you use ASE in an HCP context, yes.